# ThreadSafe Property

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

Is this threadsafe?

```
public class TestPage
{ 
    private static readonly IList<string> AcceptedItems = new List<string>() { "FOO" };

    protected void BuildSomething
    {
       TestMethod();
    }

    public static void TestMethod()
    {
       var ok = AcceptedItems.Contains("FOO")
    }  
}
```

Comment: If using .Net 4 or newer, look at using one of the many concurrent collection classes, they are specifically designed to help with thread safety.

Comment: This is threadsafe unless modified `AcceptedItems` is modified in other thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's thread-safe in the sense that the `AcceptedItems` field is guaranteed to be set before it's accessed in TestMethod. Static fields initializers are executed in the [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) of the containing type, which is guaranteed to execute before any instance is made of the class, i.e. before `BuildSomething()` is called, and before any other static field is accessed, i.e. before `TestMethod()` is called.

In addition to that, the `List<T>` can safely be accessed from multiple threads as long as the `AcceptedItems` field isn't being modified while it's being accessed. You should be aware that marking the field as `readonly` doesn't stop anyone from modifying the contents of the list, so if you have code elsewhere that does `AcceptedItems.Add(item)`, `AcceptedItems.Remove(item)` or anything similar, then you may get exceptions if that's happening while code on a different thread is also working on the same list.

Answer (score 2):

well it's not even compiling....

- no ";" in the end of `TestMethod`
- a `void` property? or a method with no "()"?

Comment: @dtb i'll remove that comment